# Using CRT to prove a single congruence relation

Tags: modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

I am trying to prove that

$2^{700} \equiv 1 \mod 3625$

and I am supposed to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem as part of my proof.

I know that the Chinese Remainder Theorem tells me that a solution to the system

$x = a_1 \mod 29$
$x = a_2 \mod 5^3$

exists because $29$ and $5^3$ multiplied together form $3625$, but I don't see how this helps me prove the original equation. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Notice if you apply Euler's theorem without first dividing into primes you get $\varphi(3625)=2800$, which is useless.

Answer (score 1):

By CRT you just have to prove:

$2^{700}\equiv 1 \bmod 29$

$2^{700}\equiv 1 \bmod 5^3$

But using Euler's theorem:

$2^{700}=(2^{\varphi(29)})^{25}\equiv 1 \bmod 29$

$2^{700}\equiv (2^{\varphi(5^3)})^7\equiv 1  \bmod 5^3$.

So the result holds. In fact this argument is a big part of the idea behind [Carmichael's lambda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function), which is the smallest integer $k$ such that $a^k\equiv 1 \bmod n$ for all $a$.

Comment: i.e. $\,\varphi(29),\varphi(5^3)\mid n\,\Rightarrow\, 2^n\equiv 1\,$ mod $\,29$ and mod $\,5^3.\,$ Said divisibility holds $\iff 700\mid n\,$ since $ {\rm lcm}(\varphi(29),\varphi(5^3)) = {\rm lcm}(28,100) = 4\cdot {\rm lcm}(7,25) = 4\cdot 7\cdot 25 =700.\,$ The same is true not only for $\,2^n\,$ but for any $\,a^n\,$ with $\,a\,$ coprime to $\,5\,$ and $\,29.\ \ $